# Enabling and disabling Laravel 6 registration from UI (e.g. button click)

Tags: laravel

It's Laravel 6 and I tried using Eloquent relationship between user and registration status table to determine the "register" value (true/false) in Auth::routes() options in the routes/web.php doesn't seem to work since it seems at that point auth()->user() has not been recognized when Laravel bootstraps the authentication routes.

Has anyone faced a similar problem and found a plausible solution?

Comment: you don't make routes dynamic like this ... leave the route where it is, a registered user should not be able to access the registration stuff anyway because of the 'guest' middleware ... if you need more conditional checks then that write your own middleware to check what you need

Comment: I was thinking, since the app needs an admin role that can decide to enable or disable user registration at anytime, wouldn't it be nice to build that on the front end so that the admin won't have to go and change the code every time he/she wants to allow user registration.